# select values in json into other json (Postgres)

Tags: json, postgresql, pipelinedb

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "eventSummaryList": [
    {
      "customer": "189256",
      "data": "{\"cliente\":\"189256\",\"data_posicao\":\"1491426372\",\"gps_valido\":\"1\",\"horimetro\":\"120561\",\"ibuttonHex\":\"0\",\"ibuttonPart1\":\"0\",\"ibuttonPart2\":\"0\",\"id_evento\":\"null\",\"id_motorista\":\"0\",\"ignicao\":\"1\",\"latitude\":\"-2222222\",\"longitude\":\"-2222222\",\"odometro\":\"253692\",\"pos_memoria\":\"0\",\"veiculo\":\"44444\",\"velocidade\":\"50\"}",
      "identifierEventRule": "77404",
      "identifierRule": "6",
      "identifierSummary": "28901976",
      "rule": "velocidade_maior_que",
      "status": 1,
      "vehicle": "44444"
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "mensagem": {
      "estilo": "SUCCESS",
      "mensagem": "Successfully executed service",
      "plataforma": "EVENT_POINT",
      "status": "SUCESSO"
    }
  }
}
```

And I need to extract the value "velocidade" what's inside "data" that 
contains another json.

I'm using the following syntax but it returns null.

```
select  cast((value::json ->'data')::json->> 'velocidade' AS   int)    AS velocidade,
```

Comment: May have better luck with:
select (select value::json ->'data'::json)->>velocidade as velocidade from ...

Comment: The content in `data` is invalid json so you need to first cleanup that before you can extract any data from it using json operators. e.g. replacing the `\"` with a simple `"` and replacing `"{` with just `{`

Comment: I did the following, but I think there should be something simpler...

 
 `regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('data'::text ,'\\', '', 'g'), '"{', '{' ), '}"' , '}')::json ->>'velocidade'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ((value::json #>> '{eventSummaryList,0,data}')::json ->> 'velocidade')::int
```

(The `#>>` or `->>` operators are the key. If you use `#>` or `->`, you'll end up with a json-encoded json string. BTW this is really a messed up model, I would look into fixing its input first/instead.)

http://rextester.com/THVYFK9026